# Java - How to use call a method from another class

Tags: java, arrays, methods

For a class project I am trying to access a method from a different class but my code gives the error "non-static method printArrayList() cannot be referenced from a static context." I am a a beginner to java so any help is appreciated.
I have simplified the code down a bit.

Here is the first class:

```
public class classOne
{
    private classTwo[] arrayList;
    public void printArray()
        {
            classTwo.printArrayList();                
        }
}
```

And the second:

```
public class classTwo
{
    public void printArrayList()
    {
        System.out.println(arrayList);        
    }     
}
```

Comment: where are you calling that methode, as error it seems you are accessing methode using class name, access it via object or define method static

Answer (score 1):

cassTwo is defined as an Array. You can reach `printArrayList()` method from a classTwo Object

You can change your code as below:

```
public class classOne
{
    private classTwo arrayList; //You have to initialize this object before you use
    public void printArray()
        {
            arrayList.printArrayList();                
        }
}
```

Comment: Still wrong. It should be `arrayList.printArrayList()`.

Comment: Thanx @MikeAllen I missed that detail

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can access the method of a class which is not static .

```
classTwo  list= new classTwo();
list.printarraylist();
```

Comment: You might want to construct that so you won't get a nullpointer ;)

Answer (score 0):

In java, non-static methods can only be invoked from or through an instance of the  containing class. Create an instance of your containing class and invoke the method through that. Also, you  need  to make the array accessible from the other class. To do this, you must pass it as a parameter, or make the other class nest or a subclass. Either way, you  must  also construct your  array for it to  print anything but `null`:

**With Parameter:**

```
public class classOne
{
    private classTwo[] arrayList = {...};  //Make sure to construct it!
    public void printArray()
        {
           //Create a new instance of classTwo
           new classTwo().printArrayList(arrayList);                
        }
}
    public class classTwo
    {
        public void printArrayList(classTwo[] arrayList) //Accept parameters
        {
            System.out.println(arrayList);        
        }     
    }
```

**With nested:**

```
public class classOne
{
    private classTwo[] arrayList = {...};  //Make sure to construct it!
    public void printArray()
        {
           //Create a new instance of classTwo
            new classTwo().printArrayList();                
        }
    public class classTwo //Nested inside of classOne
    {
        public void printArrayList()
        {
            System.out.println(arrayList);        
        }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a 'static' is one that can be accessed by different classes... put it after public so it can be transferred between classes.

```
public class classOne
{
public static classTwo[] arrayList;
public static void printArray()
    {
        classTwo.printArrayList();                
    }
}

public class classTwo
{
public satic void printArrayList()
{
    System.out.println(arrayList);        
}     
}
```

Comment: TIP: Static does *not* mean accessible by other classes. It means that the object/method can be accessed at *any time* in *any circumstance*. Static modifiers initialize their class/field/object/method when the class is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
public class classTwo
{
    // add static
    public static void printArrayList()
    {
        System.out.println(arrayList);        
    }     
}
```

Make non-static method printArrayList() to static method `public static void printArrayList()`

Solution 2:

`classTwo.printArrayList();` TO `new classTwo().printArrayList();`

The non-static method printArrayList() cannot be referenced from a static context(classTwo), so you can use `new classTwo()`.

Answer (score 0):

In this line  classTwo.printArrayList();  printArrayList is not static method so you cannot access from classTwo. You have to create object and then access the method.

```
public class classOne
{
    private classTwo[] arrayList;
    public void printArray()
    {
        classTwo obj2 = new classTwo();

        obj2.printArrayList();               
    }
}
```

or make printArrayList() method static

```
public class classTwo
{
    public static void printArrayList()
    {
        System.out.println(arrayList);        
    }     
}
```

and then access it as

```
 classTwo.printArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of your second class in your first class

```
public class classOne
{
    private classTwo[] arrayList;
    public void printArray()
    {
        classTwo obj = new classTwo();
        obj.printArrayList();                
    }
}
```

But you still have a private array in your first class, and you are trying to access it in your second class, and that is not allowed. Also you cannot name an array "arraylist" because that is a java keyword. Try making this correction to your first class....

```
static classTwo [] arr;
```

but the correct way to do it, would be to put the array list in your classTwo and keep it private, then create a constructor to construct the object to hold that arrayList then access it through the method... Let me know if you want to know more about this.

Answer (score 0):

I see 7 answers to a Question to just invoke a method of another class , Let me write mine also -

```
Method method = classTwo.getDeclaredMethod("printArrayList");
method.invoke(classTwo.newInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Method modifier to static and access that method to another class with the help of that parent class name

eg.classname.staticmethodname();